# SonataMediaBundle: change default filesystem s3 adapter

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

Is it possible to use a different class for `sonata.media.adapter.filesystem.s3` service? Right now I can see it's hardcoded in `gaufrette.php`:

```
->set('sonata.media.adapter.filesystem.s3', AwsS3::class)
    ->args(['', '', ''])
```

Is it possible to override this behaviour and set any other adapter class, e.g. `Gaufrette\Adapter\AsyncAwsS3`?

Comment: Basically you should be able to override anything in Symfony? https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#services-configuration

Answer (score 0):

According to Symfonys architecture it should be possible to override pretty much everything: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#services-configuration

> If you want to modify the services created by a bundle, you can use service decoration. If you want to do more advanced manipulations, like removing services created by other bundles, you must work with service definitions inside a compiler pass.

Most probably you solution is the latter. Here is an existing question on how to do that: [Symfony: Overriding Symfony service ( compiler pass )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511019/symfony-overriding-symfony-service-compiler-pass)

Comment: Yeah, I know the overriding mechanics of the symfony's DI. But the problem is that in this particular case a pretty complex compilation is used for this service, thus it's relatively hard to just override the service and all it's configuration via standard methods. I was looking for a more quick way to achieve this, so I thought it was somehow possible to do it via the bundle's configuration, but I didn't find anything in docs.

Comment: @ozahorulia How about an PR for the bundle or just in case they will not accept it a fork? Looks like they have poor configuration options.

Comment: yup, I already made a PR :D Looks like they didn't have such a possibility out of the box https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/pull/2358

Comment: @ozahorulia Great, good work!